# How to convert Bitmap to BitmapImage on UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, bitmap

I don't know how to convert Bitmap to BitmapImage on UWP. Not WPF.

-C#-

```
Icon appIcon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(path);
Bitmap bitmap = appIcon.ToBitmap();

BitmapImage bitmapImage = bitmap.toBitmapImage(); // It doesn't works.
DesktopIcon.Source = bitmapImage;
```

-XAML-

```
<Image Width="32" Height="32" x:Name="DesktopIcon"></Image>
```

Comment: Does `System.Drawing.Icon` work for a UWP project? It's not one of the supported APIs, although it might work by coincidence.

Comment: Hello, Brian. Syste.Drawing.Icon doesn't have error. Do you know any other way to get file's Icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do you know any other way to get file's Icon

In UWP platform, we could use `GetThumbnailAsync` to get file's `Thumbnail`, for image file we could get an empty file's thumbnail to avoid getting the image preview. You could use the following method directly.

```
public static class FileExtension
{
    public async static Task<StorageItemThumbnail> GetFileIcon(this StorageFile file, uint size = 32)
    {
        StorageItemThumbnail iconTmb;
        var imgType = new[] { "bmp", "gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" }.FirstOrDefault(ext => file.Path.ToLower().EndsWith(ext));
        if (imgType != null)
        {
            var dummy = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("dummy." + imgType , CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); //may overwrite existing
            iconTmb = await dummy.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, size);
        }
        else
        {
            iconTmb = await file.GetThumbnailAsync(ThumbnailMode.SingleItem, size);
        }
        return iconTmb;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var icon = await file.GetFileIcon();
var imgSource = new BitmapImage();
imgSource.SetSource(icon);
Myimage.Source = imgSource;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is answer !  And if you know how to get Folder Icon ? Same way?

Comment: StoragrForder has same `GetThumbnailAsync` method, please try it.